# HTML Form does not submit with forward slash

Tags: html, firefox

I was developing a simple HTML form and I couldn't figure out why the following code works on Chrome but not in Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/hello.html" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

After a while I figured out that the issue is the slash in the action url.
When the form action starts with a forward slash ('/'), the form is not submitted in firefox.
Without '/' from the action tag, pressing the 'submit' button results in a redirect to the `hello.html` page.

For me this behaviour is weird. I think it is valid to start a (relative) URL in the action attribute of a form tag with a forward slash.
Do you have some explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Wait. What's your URL? The one in the address-bar?

Comment: It starts by 'file:///' followed by the absolute path.

Comment: What you need to do is, when you are using a relative path to "no domain", you need to use `./` notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works in Google Chrome because Chrome is forgiving (or smart). What you actually mean is either:

```
<form action="hello.html" method="get">
```

or

```
<form action="./hello.html" method="get">
```

What's the difference to `/hello.html`?

Let's assume the URI of your file is `file:///c:/somedir/index.html`

`./hello.html` and `hello.html` both resolve to `file:///c:/somedir/hello.html` since they refer to the current directory. 

But `/hello.html` resolves to `file:///c:/hello.html` because according to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt (page 16)

> A relative reference beginning with a single slash character is termed
>   an absolute-path reference ...

Answer (score 0):

The following example works. I am not sure why your code doesn't work.

```
<html>
<body> 
   <form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="name">StackOverflow name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" />
        </div>
            <label for="mail">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="mail" />

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I removed `<!DOCTYPE html>` from your code, it started working too.